# Which JVM to choose for GC hacking?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a design for a GC algorithm that I would like to implement for a JVM, to allow benchmarking.

Does anyone have any experience as to which implementation would allow the easy hacking, but which still has a built in GC that would make for a meaningful comparison?

Edited:  I want a JVM that has garbage collection, as I want to collect stats using it, then rip out their GC, put my own in, and the compare.  I want it to have a good GC, as otherwise the comparison is meaning, but I want something with code that is not too difficult to work with (HotSpot has a lot of assembler, making the task more difficult)

Comment: Interesting that anyone would be inventing a new GC algorithm. Do you think you can improve on what is already there, or are you simply trying to learn more about programming?

Comment: It's a ref-counting approach with a method of cycle-breaking.  An increased memory overhead, but continuous collection.  And yes, people still work on garbage collection, it is not a solved problem.

Comment: Unless that cycle breaking is truly clever and continuous, I don't see how it's different from those existing algorithms (not used in JVMs AFAIK, but by CPython and PHP, and probably more).

Comment: It is ;)  You may wait for the paper.  Assuming benchmarking shows its worth

Comment: Did you find anything interesting? Were you able to create an improvement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the [Maxine Research VM](http://labs.oracle.com/projects/maxine/) from Oracle Labs would be a perfect match for your needs.

Quote from the first page of their [wiki](http://wikis.sun.com/display/MaxineVM/Home):

> ***Project Overview***
>
> *In this era of modern, managed languages we demand ever more from our virtual machines: better performance, more scalability, and support for the latest new languages. **Research and experimentation is essential but no longer practical** in the context of mature, complex, production VMs written in multiple languages.*
>
> *The Maxine VM is a next generation platform that establishes a new standard of productivity in this area of research. It is written entirely in Java, completely compatible with modern Java IDEs and the standard JDK, features a modular architecture that **permits alternate implementations of subsystems such as GC** and compilation to be plugged in, and is accompanied by a dedicated development tool (the Maxine Inspector) for debugging and visualizing nearly every aspect of the VM's runtime state.*

Here's an excelent video demonstrating its memory monitoring utilities:

- [Introduction to the Maxine Inspector](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOq2y5fTaHc)

Comment: Although, look more closely, this probably makes sense a place to start, but its built in GC is not very good apparently http://wikis.sun.com/display/MaxineVM/Memory+Management

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any that *don't* have a built-in GC; not much of a Java without one. Why not start with OpenJDK or Harmony?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you don't need a JVM but a virtual machine would be sufficient for testing your algorithm. Unless, you are obliged to use a JVM, you can use APache Harmony or I would recommend another  VM that was created on a phd thesis called [VmKit](http://vmkit.llvm.org/). You can take a look at it and browse the source